# SQL Stored Procedure How to Request User Input?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that returns the number of points scored by a player based on their surname - as I test, I don't keep records of this sort of thing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getpoints @surname nvarchar(30)
AS
SELECT points
FROM videogames.cod
WHERE surname = @surname
GO
```

This shows the points for the user darthvader :

```
Execute getpoints @surname = 'darthvader'
```

What changes do I need to make to the code so that I don't have to specify a username? When the procedure executes I want it to request a username and once that is entered the points are returned?

Comment: This is something you would handle in your application layer. A message box or a label to prompt users to pass a username/Surname and once user passes the required information pass that to this procedure and get the results. You only access sql server once you are sure, that once you get to sql server what you want to do there. you dont want to open a connection to sql server and then wait for user to do some sort of action and than you close the connection. Once you have made a call to sql server you want to execute it asap and get out of there.

Comment: Only I will input the data within the SQL database. Is it possible to execute the procedure and wait for an input or do I have to specify a name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is **ce n'est pas possible!** — Fundamentally, you can't.

The longer answer is that SQL Server has no way to prompt read from a keyboard or mouse. It's a data repository and access tool. For UI, you need to use something else. You can write an app to do what you want. Another possibility might be to use the facilities offered by [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) to execute your stored procedure.